# Wordpress get_header() causing whitescreen

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a theme for Wordpress using Bootstrap.

I am adding this to the top of index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

And in my header.php file there is this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

    <title><?php echo $pageName; ?> - Vampire Tints</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <center><img src="img/logo.gif" class="logo"></center>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li<?php if ($pageName=="Home"){ echo ' class="active"'; } ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li<?php if ($pageName=="About"){ echo ' class="active"'; } ?>><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li<?php if ($pageName=="Contact"){ echo ' class="active"'; } ?>><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li<?php if ($pageName=="Gallery"){ echo ' class="active"'; } ?>><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                <li<?php if ($pageName=="Vinyl Wrapping"){ echo ' class="active"'; } ?>><a href="vinyl.php">Vinyl Wrapping</a></li>
                <li<?php if ($pageName=="Tinted Lights"){ echo ' class="active"'; } ?>><a href="lights.php">Tinted Lights</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
```

Just to let you know, `get_footer()` works fine, just when I add `get_header()` the page loads blank. Also, when I use `include_one("header.php")` it works fine, but I think thats bad practice?

Many thanks!

EDIT::: The error log shows:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: get_header in /customers/a/e/4/wadeswebsolutions/httpd.www/vampiretints/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/index.php on line 4 Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /customers/a/e/4/wadeswebsolutions/httpd.www/vampiretints/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/index.php on line 4
```

As requested the index.php file:

```
    <?php
$pageName="Home";
$get_header();
?>

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3 jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="page-header"><h2>All our work comes with a<br><u><b><div class="animated tada">lifetime guarantee</div></b></u></h2></div>
          <div class="white">
          <b>Vampire Tints</b> specialises in the professional installation of car window tints, vehicle wrapping and alloy wheel refurbishment. Established in 1998 we have since built a great reputation and expanded to be one of the industries biggest and best known window tinting services. Our professional techniques, high quality finish and customer service is what sets us apart from the rest!
          </div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">Just some benefits to our tints...</div>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item benefits1">Added Privacy<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign info"></span><div class="extra"><b>Keep those peering eyes away from your personal activities!</b></div></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item benefits2">Improved Security/Safety<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign info"></span><div class="extra"><b>In an accident or break-in, our quality film helps hold shattered glass together.</b></div></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item benefits3">Toning Down Light Glare<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign info"></span><div class="extra"><b>Reducing glare from the sun and headlights, our tints are for your comfort.</b></div></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item benefits4">Reduced Solar Heat<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign info"></span><div class="extra"><b>Keeping you and your passengers up to 90% cooler in the summer!</b></div></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item benefits5">Ultra Violet Light Block<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign info"></span><div class="extra"><b>All of our shades block out at least 95% of harmful UV light, keeping you safe!</b></div></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><h4 class="text-center">Plus, it just looks good!</h4></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <div class="panel-title">Our unique process</div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body text-center">
                  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
                      <!-- Indicators -->
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                      </ol>

                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                          <div class="item active">
                              <img src="img/process/1.jpg" alt="...">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">

                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="item">
                              <img src="img/process/2.jpg" alt="...">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">

                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="item">
                              <img src="img/process/3.jpg" alt="...">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">

                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="item">
                              <img src="img/process/4.jpg" alt="...">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">

                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="item">
                              <img src="img/process/5.jpg" alt="...">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">

                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="item">
                              <img src="img/process/6.jpg" alt="...">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">

                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Controls -->
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="extra">We are one of only a few workshops in England which use the technique of <b>door glass removal</b>.</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary thetintedpanel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="page-title">
                            Coupes / Saloons
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="page-body">
                        <img class="thetinted" src="img/tinted/1.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary thetintedpanel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="page-title">
                            3 Door Cars
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="page-body">
                        <img class="thetinted" src="img/tinted/2.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary thetintedpanel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="page-title">
                            5 Door Cars
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="page-body">
                        <img class="thetinted" src="img/tinted/3.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary thetintedpanel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="page-title">
                            4x4s / MPVs
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="page-body">
                        <img class="thetinted" src="img/tinted/4.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


            <div class="alert alert-info text-center">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> We have lots of images of cars tinted by <b>Vampire Tints</b> in our Gallery.
                <br><br><a href="gallery.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View More</button></a>
            </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Any messages in the error log? That's the first place to look when you just get a white screen.

Comment: Can't access the error log, it's a remote server without those permissions :( Thanks though!

Comment: You can display errors, but it would have to be at the very top of the first script or wherever WordPress sets it: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

Comment: Thanks! Error log has been included in original question.

Comment: Are there any invisible characters around your function call? Strange error message...

Comment: Just <?php
$pageName="Home";
$get_header();
?> and then <?php get_footer(); ?> with some basic content inbetween.

Comment: can you copy the first lines of code of your theme?

Comment: Sure, I have included that in the edit above again :)

Comment: Thanks jeroen also for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, your php seems to be:

```
 <?php
 $pageName="Home";
 $get_header();
 ?>
```

`get_header()` is a function, so you should remove the `$` before it:

```
 <?php
 $pageName="Home";
 get_header();
 ?>
```

Now php is looking for a variable named `$get_header` and is trying to call the value of that variable as a function.

Comment: Thanks very much! That worked!!!! Thats funny because I used <?php get_footer(); ?> without the $, I don't know what I was thinking!!! :) Many thanks!